# How to select rows in a csv file based on a list

Tags: python, list, select, indexing, rows

I have been met with a problem. I have a list, called list `A`, and I have a data frame that has many columns. There are many time points in the first column. I want to select those rows that have the same values from list `A`. I tried to set the first column as an index. But somehow, it didn't work.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
A=[8.1, 11.7, 13.475, 14.855, 15.125, 17.465, 19.82, 24.55]
```

First column is `"Time"`. It's

```
[24.5,24.505,24.51,24.515,24.52,24.525,24.53,24.535,24.54,24.545,24.55,
24.555,24.56,24.565,24.57,24.575,24.58]
```

Comment: That's a huge list!

Comment: I deleted most of them,lol

Comment: Those numbers from list A comes from the big list. Now I want to select those rows based on those numbers.

Comment: Is the big list just a list of the column values?

Comment: yes. they comes from the first column.

Comment: "_But somehow, it didn't work_". What didn't work? Let's see your code.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
coda3 = pd.read_csv('(1) hoof2_01.csv',index_col = 0)
coda3
index = coda3.index

Comment: marker_thirteen = coda3.loc[[closest_time_points],['13:-.X', '13:-.Y', '13:-.Z']]

Comment: KeyError("None of [Index([(8.1, 11.7, 13.475, 14.855, 15.125, 17.465, 19.82, 22.5)], dtype='object', name='Time')] are in the [index]",)

Comment: the closest_time_points is list A. coda3 is the df. I used the first column as  index

Comment: `df.loc[df['Time'].isin(A)]` inspired by answer to [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/SELECT-ROWS-FROM-A-DATAFRAME-BASED-ON-VALUES-IN-A-COLUMN-IN-PANDAS)

Answer (score -1):

If you want the value,

```
for item in longList:
    if item in A:
        #The list item is found somewhere within the list A
```

Alternatively, if you want the index and/or the value,

```
for i in range(len(longList)):
    if longList[i] in A:
        #Index of item is i, value is longList[i]
```

Comment: Thanks. I also want to choose the rows based on the values we get from list A

Comment: OP has a `pandas` `Dataframe`.  Even if the OP didn't have that data structure your algorithm is inefficient.  Better would be `set_A = set(A); found = [item for item in longlist if item in set_A`].  Look ups into a set are much more efficient than linear search into a list.  But that's neither here nor there because `pandas` will end up with a very different looking solution.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I filter out questions for `pandas`, this seems to have slipped through. Also, I didn't read the entire list of items (way too big) and assumed that there may have been duplicate values.

Comment: They're time points so there is no duplicate value. I deleted some data. thanks